# Add a character before two consecutive vowels in a sentence? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to add the letter 'X' before each vowel in a string or sentence, however, when there is a repeated vowel, the letter 'X' should only be written once. For example, the word 'speeding' should look like this 'spXeedXing' but i'm getting 'spXeXedXing'.

I know why I'm getting this problem but don't know where to go from here to make it work.

Code below

```
def vowels(string):
    newString = ""
    for letter in string:
        if letter in "aeiou":
            newString += "X" + letter
        else:
            newString += letter

    print(newString)         
                
            
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    vowels("speeding")
```

Comment: add more variables.  Do not fear them.

Comment: Use an additional variable to remember the last letter before the current one and compare with the current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a new variable to track the previous letter in `string`. Check if the letters are continuous and only add `X` if the previous `char` is not the same as the current `char`.

```
def vowels(string):
    newString = ""
    i = 0 # Create a counter variable
    for letter in string:
        if (letter in "aeiou" and letter != string[i-1]) or (letter in "aeiou" and i == 0 and letter == string[i-1]): # Change this condition.  
            i += 1 
            newString += "X" + letter

        else:
            newString += letter
            i += 1 # Increment counter variable

    print(newString)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    vowels("speeding")
```

Output:

```
spXeedXing
```

Other test cases:

```
vowels("oompaloompas")
XoompXalXoompXas

vowels("eerie")
XeerXiXe
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('([aeiou]+)','X\g<1>','speeding')
'spXeedXing'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can let a regex do all the state-machine hard work...

To prepend `'X'` to any number of consecutive vowels:

```py
import re

s = 'speeding'
>>> re.sub(r'([aeiou]+)', r'X\1', s)
'spXeedXing'
```

To prepend `'X'` only to the same repeating vowel:

```py
s = 'speeding'
>>> re.sub(r'(([aeiou])\2*)', r'X\1', s)
'spXeedXing'

s = 'toaster'
>>> re.sub(r'(([aeiou])\2*)', r'X\1', s)
'tXoXastXer'
```

Comment: I understood the OP so that only two times the *same* vowel should suppress an "X" but I may be wrong.

Comment: ah, good catch - I read the question too fast. - fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple non-regex version:

```
def vowels(word):
    new_word = ""
    prev = ""  # no previous letter at first
    for letter in word:
        if letter in "aeiou" and letter != prev: 
            new_word += "X" + letter
        else:
            new_word += letter
        prev = letter  # keep to avoid insertion for repeats

    return new_word

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(vowels("speeding"))
    print(vowels("eerie"))
    print(vowels("aaaaaaaaaaaaaargh"))
```

producing

```
spXeedXing
XeerXiXe
Xaaaaaaaaaaaaaargh
```

Answer (score -1):

you should try checking the previous letter in the string to see if it is the same letter as the current index

```
def vowels(string):
    newString = ""
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if string[i] in "aeiou":
            if string[i - 1] == string[i]:
                newString += string[i]
            else:
                newString += "X" + string[i]
        else:
            newString += string[i]

print(newString)
```